# What are the essential questions that we must answer before we can launch?

Tags: discussion, scope, private-beta

Everyone, we really need to hunker down and come up with consistent guidelines for the content of this site. This post will be a container question for the substantial, site defining questions, and will eventually become a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Please do not answer this question; please go to the linked questions, answer there, and when we have a canonical answer we will place them here.

Here's a list to start us off:

- [Is it on-topic to present specific logic puzzles or brainteasers as questions?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-on-topic-to-present-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers-as-questions)

  - Followup: [Answer-voting guidelines for challenges? (specific logic puzzles or brainteasers)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/answer-voting-guidelines-for-challenges-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers)
- [Gathering chestnuts](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/gathering-chestnuts)
- [What's the etiquette of answering a 'challenge' (suggestion)](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-etiquette-of-answering-a-challenge-suggestion)
- [Does it add value to the site to re-post "been done before" questions?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/does-it-add-value-to-the-site-to-re-post-been-done-before-questions)